# Finding the key length

Tags: c, xor

**Simple XOR Decrypting:**

In order to break this encryption, we must make a few assumptions:

1) The key is reasonably short (in our case, we're going to assume it's less than 30 bytes but greater
than 3 bytes)

2) The text is plain ASCII

3) The text was written as plain English

4) The text is sufficiently longer than the key (or there are multiple text passages all encrypted with the same key)

**Description of Key Length:**

If the text is English, we know that the most prevalent characters are e,t,a,o,n,r,i,s,h,d,(...). More specifically, if we randomly pick 2 characters from any text, we know that we have greater than a 6% chance that they have the same value. The key length is less than 30 bytes.

To determine if a given key length is correct, we use those assumptions and subdivide the encrypted text into segments the same size as the key length. Then, XOR each section with the section before it and count the number of equal values. Math shows us that if Ti == Tj , then

```
Bi^Bj = (Ti^Kn)^(Tj^Kn)
      = (Ti^Tj)^(Kn^Kn)
      = (0)^(0)
      = 0
```

Then I should have the key length. But how would I get it? Only thing I have so far is read the binary file and open the binary file.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc != 2) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    printf("File Opened: %s\n", argv[1]);               
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Binary File:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DNTo.png]

For some reason, I can't post the file or post link, otherwise you guys might not have an idea.

Comment: You begin your question with a statement that makes it sound as though we should have some idea what you are talking about.  Where did the data come from?  Is this actually a programming problem or would this be better suited to the cyptography, information security or reverse engineering forums?  The only question in your posting is "How would I get it?" referring to some key for some algorithm that you don't name and for which you provide no data. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It involves with basic XOR encryption/decryption, it's an extra credit assignment.

Comment: @asdf3fasdf, sounds good but we probably need more context.  Can you reproduce the entirety of the description of the assignment that you were given?

Comment: @BrianCain I added more description. I hope it helps!

Comment: Will I graduate too if I do your homework for you?

Comment: @Havenard +1, yes you will graduate bruh

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have some data that is xored against some key. The key has fixed size and is repeated over and over to the length of the data.

Let K be the key, of length k and let P be the array with plain text and E be an array with the cipher text in it, then

```
P[0: k-1] xor K = E[0: k-1]
P[k:2l-1] xor K = E[k:2k-1]
```

so `E[0: k-1] xor E[k:2k-1]` is the same as `P[0: k-1] xor P[k:2k-1]`, that is, it's the xor of two plain text strings. You can compute the frequencies of these values from how frequently you expect certain letters to occur in the plain text and make guesses at substitutions based on those frequencies.

Construct a guess at the plain text values for `P[0: k-1]`, then xoring this guess against `E[0: k-1]` will give a guess at the K. Try the key and iterate, improving your guess. Since this is english once you have the vowels it should be pretty easy to guess.

To get the key length you need to just try all possible key-lengths, k, divide the cipher text into ranges of size k and xor pairs of them. Look at the number of character positions that agree. A good heuristic is that the most probable key length corresponds to the widest agreement among pairs.

There is a [handy tool](https://github.com/hellman/xortool) for this.